# Convert C# unit test to a method

Tags: c#, crc, crc16

I have been given some code written as a unit test for xunit. I need to use this code in my application to generate a CRC-16. How can I get the code below to return what I need?

```
    [Fact]
    public void ComputesCrc16FromTelegramOf8000()
    {
        var calculator = new CRC16();

        var test = StringToByteArray("8000");
        var result = calculator.ComputeHash(test, 0, test.Length);
        Assert.Equal((ushort) 0xC061, BitConverter.ToUInt16(result, 0));
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking us _how_ to compute a CRC-16 hash? That is, how to implement the `CRC16.ComputeHash` method?

Comment: as per my knowledge test cases are to make sure that your functionality is not broken. Not to generate code from it.

Comment: I think OP needed an example of using CRC16 and was given a unit test - he doesn't know how to change the unit test to a helper method.

Comment: Starscream1984, that is correct. I am just trying out your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add some input and return the result:

```
public Byte[] ComputeCrc16(string input) 
{
    var calculator = new CRC16();
    var bytes = StringToByteArray(input);

    return calculator.ComputeHash(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Or rather `return calculator.ComputeHash(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)`

Comment: Remove the `=`, also you need to set the return type to `byte[]`

Comment: This works for the given question, however the CRC output is wrong. I have made a further post here for anyone interested - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860356/how-to-generate-a-crc-16-from-c-sharp