# System.OverflowException computing CRC-16 on C#

Tags: c#, overflow, crc16

I'm trying to use the code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22861111/3080027) but I get a System.OverflowException on the line `byte index = (byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]);` 
This happens on the next iteration after the first non-zero byte. I'm not sure what to check.

Thanks in advance.

SharpDevelop Version : 5.1.0.5134-RC-d5052dc5
.NET Version         : 4.6.00079
OS Version           : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0

Comment: Using SharpDevelop is surely the underlying reason.  Whether this code bombs depends on a compiler option, `/checked`.  Always off by default in Visual Studio.  Dig through the project setting dialog to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you building with [arithmetic overflow checking enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx), but the answer assumes that this is not the case.  By default, [checking is disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx), so it's not uncommon to see this assumption made.

In the code in question:

```
    public static ushort ComputeChecksum(byte[] bytes)
    {
        ushort crc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
        {
            byte index = (byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]);
            crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ table[index]);
        }
        return crc;
    }
```

`crc` is an unsigned short while `index` is a byte, so `(crc ^ bytes[i])` could clearly be larger than 255 and make the conversion to `byte` overflow in a checked environment.

If I change the line to be explicitly [`unchecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx):

```
            byte index = unchecked((byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]));
```

Then the overflow no longer occurs.