# CRC-16 Algorithm using polynom 0x8005

Tags: c#, vb.net, algorithm

I'm writing an MPEG Header reader and some of my files have a CRC, 2 Bytes,  directly following the header. I need to calculate the CRC so I can compare it to validate I'm reading the correct frame header. I need and example of the CRC-16 algorithm using polynom 0x8005. I don't understand the algorithm I need to use. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22860356/1070452  There are actually quite a few implementations here...put your google to work

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860356/how-to-generate-a-crc-16-from-c-sharp  If you've already read this, could you explain more about what specifically you don't understand?

Comment: Thanks for the links guys. This helps a lot.