# CRC 16, C to C#

Tags: c#, c, crc, crc16

I have this code sample of CRC-16 calculation and I want to convert it to C#.  It have to stay with the same logic because it works with other machines.

I saw this [crc16 from c to c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976957/crc-16-0x8005-polynominal-from-c-to-c-sos) but it doesn't work (different result), maybe because of the variable types.

The original code is: Input char = 'A', remainder = 0, Output = 390

```
#define CRC_POLYNOMIAL 0x8005 /* CRC polynomial */
short Calculate_CRC ( char ch, short remainder ){
    char *ch_ptr;
    int i;
    // the different part
    ch_ptr = (char*)&remainder;
    *(ch_ptr+1) = *(ch_ptr+1) ^ ch; /* exclusive or ch with msb of remainder */
    for (i=0; i<=7; i++)
        if (remainder < 0)
        { /* msb of remainder = 1 */
            remainder = remainder << 1;
            remainder = remainder ^ CRC_POLYNOMIAL;
        }
        else
            remainder = remainder << 1;
    return (remainder);
}
```

and my code is:  Input char = 'A', remainder = 0, Output = 514

```
    static public ushort func(byte ch, ushort remainder, int f) {
        // the different part
        byte[] rawCrc = new byte[2];
        rawCrc[0] = (byte)(remainder & 0x00FF);
        rawCrc[1] = (byte)((remainder >> 8) & 0x00FF);
        rawCrc[0] ^= ch;
        remainder &= (byte)(rawCrc[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
            if ((remainder & (0x8000)) == 0) { /* msb of remainder = 1 */
                remainder <<= 1;
                remainder ^= POL;
            }
            else
                remainder <<= 1;
        return remainder;
    }
```

The result is different but as I can see, my code still doing the xor with the msb as needed.

How can I fix it?

TIA

Comment: Whats the issue? Can you put your error exception in your post as well?

Comment: different result

Comment: At which step to the state of the two implementations start to differ?

Comment: Only the part before the loop

Comment: huh? At which specific line? Which values are different? What are the different values?

Comment: And you didn't provide the inputs that result in a problem.

Comment: I don't seen an equivalent to `remainder &= (byte)(rawCrc[0]);` in the C snippet you posted

Comment: I just updated, the & operation should fix the issue for changing remainder because I don't have pointers

Comment: Re "*I just updated*", Yet you didn't answer my questions?

Comment: Re "*the & operation should fix the issue for changing remainder*", Again, there is no corresponding change in the C snippet you posted

Comment: So how would you convert the two C lines(before the loop) to C#?

Answer (score 2):

Your C# code is not equivalent to your C code.  Specifically, this:

> ```
>         rawCrc[0] ^= ch;
> ```

... XORs `ch` with the *least*-significant byte of `remainder`, whereas the corresponding operation in the C code is an XOR with the *most*-significant byte.

Furthermore, this C# line:

> ```
>         remainder &= (byte)(rawCrc[0]);
> ```

... does not appear to correspond to anything in the C code, and it looks wrong on its face.  I suppose that you mean to recompose the two bytes into `remainder`, but that doesn't do it.  I would suggest doing without `rawCrc` altogether, and instead doing something like

```
            remainder = remainder ^ ((ch & 0xff) << 8);
```

Also, the test in this C# `if` statement:

> ```
>             if ((remainder & (0x8000)) == 0) { /* msb of remainder = 1 */
> ```

... is reversed relative to the corresponding test in the C code, and inconsistent with the meaning asserted by the trailing comment.

Comment: It still returns the same result.

Comment: I don't know what "it" you mean, since I did not give you a complete re-written solution, but if you're saying that you fixed all of the issues I pointed out but your C# code produces the same result then either (i) you are mistaken, or (ii) the reason for that is elsewhere.

Comment: As you can see in the other answer, the code is a bit different so maybe the problam was elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

Try this... It should (SHOULD) be equivalent to the C version. Note that I removed the `byte[]` array.

```
const short CRC_POLYNOMIAL = unchecked((short)0x8005);

static short Calculate_CRC(byte ch, short remainder)
{
    short ch_ptr = (short)(remainder & 0xFF);
    ch_ptr |= (short)((remainder & 0xFF00) ^ (ch << 8));

    // You could directly use ch_ptr from now on!
    remainder = ch_ptr;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        if (remainder < 0)
        { /* msb of remainder = 1 */
            remainder = (short)(remainder << 1);
            remainder = (short)(remainder ^ CRC_POLYNOMIAL);
        }
        else
        {
            remainder = (short)(remainder << 1);
        }
    }

    return remainder;
}
```

Note that I would normally remove the `short` and change it to `ushort`. Just thinking that there is a bit sign in something that should be treated as bits makes me want to puke.

```
const ushort CRC_POLYNOMIAL = (ushort)0x8005;

static ushort Calculate_CRC(byte ch, ushort remainder)
{
    ushort remainder2 = (ushort)(remainder & 0xFF);
    remainder2 |= (ushort)((remainder & 0xFF00) ^ (ch << 8));

    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        if (remainder2 > short.MaxValue)
        { /* msb of remainder = 1 */
            remainder2 = (ushort)(remainder2 << 1);
            remainder2 = (ushort)(remainder2 ^ CRC_POLYNOMIAL);
        }
        else
        {
            remainder2 = (ushort)(remainder2 << 1);
        }
    }

    return remainder2;
}
```

Comment: The second code return 0, but the first one is working (at least for my example). Thank you!

Comment: @RoyAncri Corrected the second version... This happens when you program directly in the SO edit box :-)

Answer (score 2):

This line in the C code: `*(ch_ptr+1) = *(ch_ptr+1) ^ ch;` is exclusive-oring `ch` onto the *high* byte of `remainder`. It is a horrible way to do it, since that would fail on a big-endian machine. What they should have done, in C, is `remainder ^= (short)ch << 8;`. That would be portable, as well as more obvious to the reader what's going on. That is what I did in the C# code below, with the appropriate casting for C# (which seems to have really odd implicit promotion rules):

```
static ushort Calculate_CRC(byte ch, ushort crc) {
    crc ^= (ushort)(ch << 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        crc = (ushort)((crc & 0x8000) == 0 ? crc << 1 : (crc << 1) ^ 0x8005);
    return crc;
}
```