# Calculating the PPP Frame Check Sequence

Tags: c#, crc, crc16, ppp

I'm attempting to generate a valid PPP Frame Check Sequence (FCS) using C#.  The code I have implemented is based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22861111).

```
public static class Crc16
{
    const ushort polynomial = 0x8408;
    static readonly ushort[] fcstab = new ushort[256];

    // This is the fcstab from RFC1662
    // https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1662#ref-7
    //static readonly ushort[] fcstab = new ushort[] {
    //      0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf,
    //      0x8c48, 0x9dc1, 0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c, 0xdbe5, 0xe97e, 0xf8f7,
    //      0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a, 0x56a5, 0x472c, 0x75b7, 0x643e,
    //      0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed, 0xcb64, 0xf9ff, 0xe876,
    //      0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76af, 0x4434, 0x55bd,
    //      0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e, 0xfae7, 0xc87c, 0xd9f5,
    //      0x3183, 0x200a, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7, 0x662e, 0x54b5, 0x453c,
    //      0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50, 0xfbef, 0xea66, 0xd8fd, 0xc974,
    //      0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420, 0x15a9, 0x2732, 0x36bb,
    //      0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868, 0x99e1, 0xab7a, 0xbaf3,
    //      0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1, 0x0528, 0x37b3, 0x263a,
    //      0xdecd, 0xcf44, 0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9, 0x8960, 0xbbfb, 0xaa72,
    //      0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d, 0x2522, 0x34ab, 0x0630, 0x17b9,
    //      0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a, 0xb8e3, 0x8a78, 0x9bf1,
    //      0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3, 0x242a, 0x16b1, 0x0738,
    //      0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb, 0xa862, 0x9af9, 0x8b70,
    //      0x8408, 0x9581, 0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c, 0xd3a5, 0xe13e, 0xf0b7,
    //      0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb, 0x4e64, 0x5fed, 0x6d76, 0x7cff,
    //      0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad, 0xc324, 0xf1bf, 0xe036,
    //      0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5, 0x4f6c, 0x7df7, 0x6c7e,
    //      0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e, 0xf2a7, 0xc03c, 0xd1b5,
    //      0x2942, 0x38cb, 0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66, 0x7eef, 0x4c74, 0x5dfd,
    //      0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xf3af, 0xe226, 0xd0bd, 0xc134,
    //      0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7, 0x6e6e, 0x5cf5, 0x4d7c,
    //      0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028, 0x91a1, 0xa33a, 0xb2b3,
    //      0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60, 0x1de9, 0x2f72, 0x3efb,
    //      0xd68d, 0xc704, 0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9, 0x8120, 0xb3bb, 0xa232,
    //      0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e, 0x1ce1, 0x0d68, 0x3ff3, 0x2e7a,
    //      0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a, 0xb0a3, 0x8238, 0x93b1,
    //      0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62, 0x3ceb, 0x0e70, 0x1ff9,
    //      0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab, 0xa022, 0x92b9, 0x8330,
    //      0x7bc7, 0x6a4e, 0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3, 0x2c6a, 0x1ef1, 0x0f78
    //   };

    static Crc16()
    {
        ushort value;
        ushort temp;
        for (ushort i = 0; i < fcstab.Length; ++i)
        {
            value = 0;
            temp = i;
            for (byte j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            {
                if (((value ^ temp) & 0x0001) != 0)
                {
                    value = (ushort)((value >> 1) ^ polynomial);
                }
                else
                {
                    value >>= 1;
                }
                temp >>= 1;
            }
            fcstab[i] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Method that computes the checksum.</summary>
    /// <param name="buff">The input <see cref="byte[]"/> to calculate the checksum off of.</param>
    /// <example>
    /// byte[] fcs = Crc16.ComputeChecksumBytes(buff)
    /// </example>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] ComputeChecksumBytes(byte[] buff)
    {
        ushort fcs = 0xFFFF;
        for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
        {
            byte index = (byte)((fcs ^ buff[i]) & 0xff);
            fcs = (ushort)((fcs >> 8) ^ fcstab[index]);
        }
        fcs ^= 0xFFFF;
        var lsb = (fcs >> 8) & 0xff;
        var msb = fcs & 0xff;
        return new byte[] { (byte)msb, (byte)lsb }; 
    }
}
```

The good part is that the FCS table (`fcstab[]`) that gets generated is the same table seen in [RFC 1662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1662#appendix-C.2) thus confirming that the code in the constructor is correct.

The problem seems to be with the ComputeChecksumBytes() method.

I have an input PPP Packet of `7E FF 03 C0 21 01 00 00 0E 02 06 00 00 00 00 07 02 08 02 DD 31 7E`.

I know from [this link](http://www.netfor2.com/fcs.htm) that the "FCS is calculated over the **entire** PPP packet, not including the start and stop flags (`7E`)."  This leaves me with `FF 03 C0 21 01 00 00 0E 02 06 00 00 00 00 07 02 08 02 DD 31`.

I also know from [that link](http://www.netfor2.com/fcs.htm) that the FCS octets (`DD 31`) are to be "made equal to zero".  This leaves me with `FF 03 C0 21 01 00 00 0E 02 06 00 00 00 00 07 02 08 02 00 00`.

When I call `Crc16.ComputeChecksumBytes` with that input byte array, my actual calculated FCS ends up being `C0 0E`.

Everything I'm doing seems to be correct but I *still* cannot figure out why I'm not getting the `DD 31` that was calculated in the original packet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With the zeros it should be `c00e`, not `2d24`. There must be something else wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it without the two 0's at the end.

Comment: Some extra explanation would be good for future readers. You're a very high rep user, you know that good answers normally have a bit more of an explanation otherwise they get flagged (like this did!). I'm sure it might answer the question, but you need to explain why it does. - From Review.

Comment: The OP would need to explain why they put two 0's on the end in the first place! I have no idea why they did that.

Comment: Yeah, admittedly I struggled with that, but I felt I should at least leave a comment so I could hit the 'Looks OK' button in the review queue!

Comment: @MarkAdler the FCS was swapped with the zeros because of this comment in [this link](http://www.netfor2.com/fcs.htm), "u16 buff[] is an array containing all octets in the packet with the FCS octets made equal to zero".

Comment: @MarkAdler guess that's what I get for believing everything I read on the interwebs! I'll update the original post to clarify that specific detail is not correct.