# Map from fixed length string to a unique number

Tags: c#, .net, mapping

I'm looking for an algorithm (or hash, etc...) that can map a fixed length string (15 character) to unique number (5 digits). I expect it to map `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO` to `12450` or `ONMLKJIHGFEDCBA` to `15647` (The generated number must be unique).

Comment: Just do a 16bit CRC, pad it with 0's or something, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860356/how-to-generate-a-crc-16-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

it's not possible to map

> a fixed length string (15 character)

into a

> unique number (5 digits)

because `15` characters with `26` possible characters (A-Z)  `>` than  `5` digits with `10` possible digits (0-9)

so `26^15 > 10^5` or `1.677.259.342.285.725.925.376 > 100.000`

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is impossible.

There are more possible 15 character strings than there are possible 5 digit numbers. Therefore it is impossible to map each string to a unique number.

Answer (score 0):

It is truly impossible to do that. Unless, if you change it into alphanumeric, maybe that could work.